# Determine if this is a subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Decide whether or not S is a subring of R, when S is the set of functions which are linear combinations with integer coefficients of the functions $\{1, \cos{nt}, \sin{nt}\}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and R is the set of all real valued functions of t.

It is easy to show that S is closed under addition and that it has the multiplicative identity but I cannot prove that it is not closed under multiplication (which is what I suspect).

Comment: It actually is closed under multiplication.

Comment: even with integer coefficients? Let f(t)=sint and g(t)=cost then (fg)(t)=½sin(2t) can this be an integer linear combination? and can you explain?

Comment: @MattSamuel Only if you allows for rational coefficients.

Comment: Oh, integer coefficients. I missed that. It's closed with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Prove first that $\{1, \cos{nt}, \sin{nt}\}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb R$).

Then use
$$\sin(t)\cos(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$
to deduce that this is the **only** way of writing $\sin(t)\cos(t)$ as a linear combination of $S$ with rational, **hence integer** coefficients.

**P.S.** The linear independence is typically obtained for free from the fact that the set is Orthogonal with respect to the inner product
$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt$$

Comment: Can I just use this as a counterfactual?

Comment: I see why that is not sufficient now. OK I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

$ ( 1 + \cos t) . \sin t = \sin t + \sin (2t) /2  \not \in S $

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. So what you are saying is that $(1+\cos{t})$ and $\sin{t}$ are both elements of $S$ but their product is not. So therefore $S$ is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Yes!! Absolutely

Comment: Only looking at the form of elements is not an argument to conclude that you got something outside of $S$.